# I get a not a P2TR scriptPubKey error when trying to generate a bech32m taproot compliant P2TR address with python

Tags: python, taproot, p2tr, bip350-bech32m

I have the following script that is supposed to derive a taproot P2TR address:

```python
from bitcointx import set_custom_secp256k1_path
set_custom_secp256k1_path('./bitcointx_secp256k1_here/libsecp256k1.2.dylib')

from bitcointx.wallet import P2TRBitcoinTestnetAddress, P2TRCoinAddress, CBitcoinTestnetKey, CBitcoinTestnetExtKey
from bitcointx.core.script import (CScript, OP_CHECKSIG, OP_NUMEQUAL, CScriptWitness)


sender_priv_key = CBitcoinTestnetExtKey('PRIVATE KEY TESTNET EXTENDED WIF')
sender_pub_key = sender_priv_key.pub
csript_from_pub = CScript([sender_pub_key, OP_CHECKSIG])
print(csript_from_pub)
addrs_for_script = P2TRBitcoinTestnetAddress.from_scriptPubKey(csript_from_pub)
print(addrs_for_script)
```

But all that this prints in my terminal is:

```
b'!\x02\x8fy\x12\xc2\xc1kO\x0er\xfc\x98\xeaM\x87X\xee\xbbf\x16\xd9\x02\x9e\xca-\xdc\xea\x03\xb2\x02k\x07{\xac'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Dev/bit_useful_scripts/simple_send_from_segv1.py", line 12, in <module>
    addrs_for_script = P2TRBitcoinTestnetAddress.from_scriptPubKey(csript_from_pub)
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/py_scratch_310_071722/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcointx/util.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/py_scratch_310_071722/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcointx/wallet.py", line 504, in from_scriptPubKey
    raise P2TRCoinAddressError('not a P2TR scriptPubKey')
bitcointx.wallet.P2TRCoinAddressError: not a P2TR scriptPubKey
```

It fails with a "not a P2TR scriptPubKey" error.

I know that 'PRIVATE KEY TESTNET EXTENDED WIF' is capable of producing a P2TR address. What am I doing wrong?